# laravel - how to sort by grouped after get()

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This query is working good. It brings the totals for each city according to groupBy method.

```
$cities = Washticket::whereDate('used_at', $date)
                      ->get()
                      ->groupBy('place_used.state');
```

Now I want the list sorted showing up biggest numbers first.

How can I do that?

Comment: Multiple ways to do that: https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-group-by-with-order-by-desc-in-laravelexample.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use orderBy

```
$cities = Washticket::query()
    ->whereDate('used_at', $date)
    ->orderBy('place_used.state', 'desc)
    ->groupBy('place_used.state')
    ->get();
```

Comment: it doesn't work saying `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'place_used.state' in 'group statement'`

Comment: @RuiCosta that would also be my preferred solution.

Comment: @anderlaini `->orderBy('place_used.state', 'desc' )` missing -> ` <-

Comment: Do the group by before the order by

Comment: If the column doesn't exists, then your first query can't work well. Replace that column for the one you need

Comment: Additionally, you don't need `::query()`; you can start this with `Washticket::whereDate()`. `::query()` is useful if you want to start a query and chain things, like `$query = Washticket::query();`, then later, `$query->where(...)`, etc etc.